# How to check value of enumeration variables in their symbolic form in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, enumeration

I'm new to C, and want to know **how to check value of enumeration variables in their symbolic form in GDB**?

Here is my test code:

```c
int main () 
{
    enum months {JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN,
                 JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC }myMon;
    printf("%d\n", JAN);
    
    return 0;
}
```

In GDB, I set breakpoint in the line `printf("%d\n", JAN);`, and try to check value of `myMon` in its symbolic form, and got the following:

```
(gdb) p myMon
$1 = 0
```

I wonder if any possible to print values of `myMon` in **its symbolic form**?

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: `enum months` is a type name, you can't print a type. You might be able to print specific values of it though, or a variable having this type.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that. I've updated my question about it and add more description about what I really want to know.

Comment: I am not sure GDB is capable of this

Comment: `printf` will never be able to print the symbolic name (unless you write code to look it up in a table of strings), but that's an entirely separate question.

Comment: @NateEldredge You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `p` command will do this, but only if the variable is set to a value that matches one of the named enum constants.  Here `myMon` equals 0 (apparently by chance, since you left it uninitialized), whereas you set your enum constants to start at 1, so 0 isn't any of them.  In this case gdb falls back to printing it as an integer.

Try `myMon = AUG;`, and then on subsequent lines, `p myMon` will display `$1 = AUG` as desired.

Make sure you are compiling with `-g` in order for all of this to work.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, it does work as desired!